# PostgreSQL query to find rows with matching data and combining columns from those rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and have a table like this which shows users, items and review scores to item given by the user (it is possible for a user to give more than one scores to a specific item):

```
  name   |    item   | score
---------+-----------+-------
 user_1  |  item_1   |  3
 user_1  |  item_2   |  2
 user_1  |  item_3   |  3
 user_1  |  item_4   |  4
 user_1  |  item_1   |  5
 user_2  |  item_1   |  5
 user_2  |  item_2   |  2
 user_3  |  item_3   |  1
 user_4  |  item_3   |  1
```

I want to make a query which 1) selects the items that have been given a same score by two different users and 2) prints the results in following form:

```
  name1  |   name2  |  item  | score
---------+----------+--------+-------
 user_1  |  user_2  | item_1 |   5
 user_2  |  user_1  | item_1 |   5
 user_1  |  user_2  | item_2 |   2
 user_2  |  user_1  | item_2 |   2
 user_3  |  user_4  | item_3 |   1
 user_4  |  user_3  | item_3 |   1
```

I haven't even gotten close to a solution. How can you make a condition for selecting the user column twice, with different values, into one result row, based on specific condition (in this case, need to have a common item with a same score). And how to then get the same two user values, but in different order, for the next row.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical join will do:

```
select 
    t1.name, t2.name, t1.item, t1.score
  from mytable t1
  join mytable t2 on t1.item = t2.item and t1.score = t2.score
  where t1.name <> t2.name
```

If you want to avoid repeating tuples, change the `WHERE` condition, as in:

```
select 
    t1.name, t2.name, t1.item, t1.score
  from mytable t1
  join mytable t2 on t1.item = t2.item and t1.score = t2.score
  where t1.name < t2.name
```

Comment: Technically the asker has both directions in there (see user_1, user_2 swapped in first two rows of output) so it should just be `where t1.name<>t2.name`

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is a self-join:

```
SELECT a.name AS name1, b.name AS name2, a.item, a.score
FROM table a INNER JOIN table b
ON a.item = b.item AND a.score = b.score
WHERE a.name != b.name
```

Comment: This query will return wrong tuples, such as (user1, user1).